# What is non-serializable schedule? in transaction database

Tags: database, transactions, information-retrieval

Can anyone explain me what is  non-serializable in transaction DB. please give me an example.  r1(x) r2(x)w1(y) c2 c1 is this non-serializable?

Answer (score 3):

Imagine this table (in `Oracle`):

```
CREATE TABLE t_series (id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, value INT NOT NULL)

INSERT
INTO    t_series
VALUES  (1, 1)

INSERT
INTO    t_series
VALUES  (2, 2)
```

Now we start two `READ COMMITTED` transactions in two sessions:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED
```

and issue the following queries:

```
-- session 1
UPDATE  t_series
SET     value = 1
WHERE   value = 2
/
COMMIT
/
```

and, then:

```
-- session 2
UPDATE  t_series
SET     value = 2
WHERE   value = 1
/
COMMIT
/
```

The outcome will be this:

```
id   value
1    2
2    2
```

, i. e. both records will have `value = 2`

The first query made both records to have `value = 1`, the second query saw these changes and made both records to have `value = 2`.

If we did the same with `SERIALIZABLE` level, the outcome would be this:

```
id   value
1    2
2    1
```

, i. e. the queries will just swap the `value`'s

**A serializable transaction sees the database in exactly same state it was when the transaction had begun, except for the changes made by the transaction itself.**